# http request POST with javascript using Java/Python?

Tags: javascript, python, phantomjs

I try to connect to http://leya2.eu/.
I´ve tried a lot of things... the problem is to run the Script on the Website.
I do want to do it with Python or Java... last thing i tried was PhatomJS, but i only got the BlazingFast Page like everytime.

The Problem is this script:

```
var XHR="onload"in new XMLHttpRequest?XMLHttpRequest:XDomainRequest,xhr=new XHR;var ww = $(window).width();xhr.open("GET","/___S___/?rid=CLYVwTkbSONnYzhmsnBo6AhooeCoHsgxayFRarvktEYBIdpcL2aQPVoW7U32QGrh&sid=" + ww +"&d=leya2.eu&tz=1500505915.508",true),xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4==xhr.readyState&&(xhr.status==200)){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.text=xhr.responseText,document.body.appendChild(t)}},xhr.send(null);function wait(){}; setTimeout(wait(),4000);
```

So maybe someone got an idea ?

my standard script is like:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = 'http://evidence-server.com/?s=login'
response = urlopen(url, urlencode(data).encode("utf-8"))
content = response.read().decode(response.headers.get_content_charset())
print(content)
```

This allready was near:

```
var page = require("webpage").create(),
    url = "http://leya2.eu/";

function onPageReady() {
    var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    });

    console.log(htmlContent);

    phantom.exit();
}
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(htmlContent);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 5000); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working script to access your target site. Notice a built-in variable `page.content`:

```
var page = require("webpage").create(),
    url = "http://leya2.eu/";


page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render("leya2.jpg");
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 10000); 
    }
});
```

Produces [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJACq.jpg) on PhantomJS version 2.5b for Windows.

Comment: Do you know, how i can do this in casper ?

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start("http://leya2.eu/", function() {
 window.setTimeout(function () {
 casper.render("leya2.jpg");
 console.log(casper.content);

Comment: You should probably open another question.